# How to Auto Increment a Column with Rows that have the same Value

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

Ok, I have this example MySQL DB Here

```
id | groupid | name
1      1       Bob
2      1       Some Name
3      3       /dev/null
4      3       Moo
5      4       Jane
```

Now, with what SQL query can I increment the `groupid` column so it shows up like this:

```
id | groupid | name
1      1       Bob
2      1       Some Name
3      2       /dev/null
4      2       Moo
5      3       Jane
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables:

```
  select t.id, t.name,
         (@rn := if(@g = groupid, @rn + 1,
                    if(@g := groupid, 1, 1)
                   )
         ) as groupid
  from t cross join
       (select @g := 0, @rn := 0) params
  order by t.group_id, t.id;
```

If you actually want to change the values, you can incorporate similar logic into an `update`.

EDIT:

The simplest way to use the above in an `update` is to `join` it in:

```
update t join
       (select t.id, t.name,
               (@rn := if(@g = groupid, @rn + 1,
                          if(@g := groupid, 1, 1)
                         )
               ) as new_groupid
        from t cross join
             (select @g := 0, @rn := 0) params
       order by t.group_id, t.id
      ) tt
      on t.id = tt.id
    set t.groupid = tt.new_groupid;
```

Comment: This didn't work and just replaced the `groupid` field with random numbers.

Comment: Does the first query produce the right numbers for the groups?

Comment: @Sarabveer . . . It is pretty formulaic, so I'm surprised it doesn't do what you want.